# Subset data.table by column index that comes from another object (size 1 numeric vector)

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I am trying to subset a data.table based on parameters `l` (line number) and `cn` (column number) number, which are themselves objects. Subsetting based on `l` seems to work. But subsetting on `cn` (or `get(cn)`) never works.

For example:

```
> dt <- iris %>% data.table()
> 
> #Subseting (works)
> dt[10,3]
   Petal.Length
1:          1.5
> 
> #Subseting by exteral parameter (object)
> cn <- 3 # Petal.Length
> l <- 10
> dt[l,3] #works
   Petal.Length
1:          1.5
> dt[10,cn]
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, 10, cn) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'cn' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..c]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
> dt[l,cn]
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, l, cn) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'cn' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..c]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
> dt[l,get(cn)]
Error in get(cn) : invalid first argument
```

Is there a way to subset column number coming from an external object?

Comment: `dt[l,..c]` should work. (Bad choice for a variable name btw).

Comment: @DavidArenburg, tks. This Works. Please write this as the answer so that I can mark it as the answer. I am curious as to what is happening. Why this obscure trick? etc. I fixed the c name, tks for this too

Comment: It's not a trick. It's mainly because by default data.table does a non-standard evaluation, e.g., it parsing unquoted column names, e.g. `dt[, Petal.Length]`, is the default behavior while in base R it would be `df[, "Petal.Length"]`. Hence, when you want to pass something like `dt[, variable]` to a data.table it needs to understand, if this an unquoted column names, some functions perhaps (in your case `c` is indeed also a function) or a variable. `..variable` helps it understand how to parse your request. While for a `data.frame` it is easy as it knows that everything unquoted is a variable.